# Why does my cell reference in excel automatically become superindexed every time i press enter?

Tags: excel

Why does my M2 cell reference in excel (for example =M2) automatically become =M² every time i press enter? 
The same happens for O2 cell references except it becomes subscript. 
I am using english language based excel version 2013.

Comment: Look at the AutoCorrect list in File > Options > Proofing > Autocorrect Options. Are there any spurious entries?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, look at the AutoCorrect list in

> File > Options > Proofing > Autocorrect Options

and check for entries matching your specific problems above.

I expect they were manually added at some point in the past.

[image: Autocorrect settings]